# Is an inductor in a necessary ground loop useful for limiting noise in ground loops?

Tags: filter, ground-loop

I am looking to ground several devices together that all ground to a common PC, and want to at least eliminate any HF noise between the grounds. It occurs to me an appropriately sized inductor series in the ground path would keep the grounds together while eliminating noise, but I can't see this as an accepted solution anywhere. Is there any good reason for that?

In terms of induced currents in the loops, would an appropriately sized resistor at least minimise their effect while being conductive enough to maintain the ground level sufficiently?

The circuits are primarily for sensing so noise and offset are the prime objective as opposed to low-resistance safety-grounding.

The closest I have seen is LC filters, but not sure what is being implemented exactly and between where.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4bl1O.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: It can help with HF noise but a true ground loop tends to mainly be problematic at 50Hz (or 60Hz depending on locale)

Comment: Draw out your proposal to reduce ambiguity in your words.

Comment: Connect which devices together and how? If the devices are not grounded then there are no ground loops. But even a typical monitor is grounded, so you will propably already have ground loops between grounded equipment.

Comment: @Andyaka I've added a schematic, and looking at it, the grounding is a mess and I don't know if what I'm proposing could possibly work.

Comment: What you've drawn makes no sense because the inductors are shorted by wires in the device under test.

Comment: @Andyaka On review I've resolved that now by including additional elements to the circuit under test. I am looking for solutions here, so it will make sense that what I'm drawing doesn't work. I think if this solution has any merit, then the ground stars out from the mains and has no strong loops anywhere else.

Comment: Just use differential measurement amplifiers.

Comment: @Andyaka I get that they are a great solution when budget permits, but it doesn't answer this question.

Comment: They aren't expensive - I mean if you are using an op-amp front end then adding two more resistors is not going to be expensive unless of course you've already designed and had built single ended amplifiers.

Answer (score 3):

> But I can't see this as an accepted solution anywhere. Is there any
> good reason for that?

This is a very common solution and most people have probably encountered a ferrite clamp on a cable at some point in their life. Many cables use a ferrite clamp to reduce high frequency noise on the shield.

High frequency currents take the path of least inductance, so the idea is to increase inductance to "block" currents and allow them to return to the source. (instead of going to create noise somewhere else). This can be done by placing an inductor in series on the conductor. This will affect rise times so care needs to be taken if digital signals are involved. In many cases ferrites are applied to shields to block high frequency currents.

Edit:
In your case a ferrite inductor would be entirely appropriate for your application to filter out noise on the power input lines

[image]
Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferrite_bead

Comment: Ah thanks for the response, I did neglect these in my answer, though only that I'd read they're only useful for RF like you say, not as much for lower frequencies. What I'm looking for is a way of grounding all my elements while minimising induced loop currents, (primarily of noise, but had some consideration of DC as well.)

Comment: If you want to block DC then also use a resistor (or capacitor and block DC entirely), but this comes at a cost as very little current will follow across the conductor and most applications either want DC (power). They make ferrite inductors with very low frequency cutoffs that attenuate frequencies in the 10s of Hz